# Detecting value in listbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

I have a dropdown box (Sub District) and a "listbox_source" (villages). I prepare value for the dropdown and listbox from sql server and listbox's values depend on drop down, dynamic.

Then, I have another "listbox_destination" for moving selected village from "listbox_source". I've done for moving value from **listbox_source** to **listbox_destination**.

but, then, there is questions,

1. how do I know if **listbox_destination** still empty or has values ?
2. how  do I know if there is no double value in **listbox_destination**
   when Sub District dropdown was selected for the second time and with
   the same value ?

Please, advice...

I try give an example of my code:
Dropdown:

```
<select id="ID_Villages" size="10" multiple="">
<option value="42">Bandul</option>
<option value="43">Dedap</option>
<option value="44">Mekar Delima</option>
<option value="45">Putri Puyu</option>
<option value="46">Tanjung Padang</option>
<option value="47">Tanjung Pisang</option>
<option value="187">Kudap</option>
<option value="188">Selat Akar</option>
<option value="189">Mengkopot</option>
<option value="190">Mengkirau</option>


$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#btn_To_Right').click(function (e) {
        var selectedList = $('#ID_Villages  option:selected').toArray();

        if ($('selectedList').length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();

        } else {
            <!-- #1. how to check listbox_destination still empty or has values ? -->

            $(selectedVillage).append($(selectedList).clone());
            $(selectedList).remove();
            alert(selectedVillage.length);

            } else {
                <!-- #2. how to avoid double values -->    
                $each(selectedList, function (index, value) {
                    if($selectedVillage ??? ).length == 0){

                        <!-- add new value -->

                    } else {
                        alert ("data already exist");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

**UPDATE**
for first moving (**#1**), from **listbox_source** to **listox_destination**, I check **listox_destination** by using

```
if ($("#lst_ID_Desa_Selected option").length == 0) {
    $(selectedVillage).append($(selectedList).clone());
    $(selectedList).remove();
}
```

and then for double values protection (**#2**)

```
$.each(selectedList, function (index, value) { 
    alert($("selectedList option[value='" + 42 + "']").length);
    alert($("selectedList option[value='" + value.value + "']"));
    alert($("selectedList <option value='" + value.value + "'>"));

})
```

---

I tried to get value from

```
alert($("selectedList option[value='" + value + "']").length);
```

by using alert but popup value appears "0". Whereas, **selectedList** is the source data of villages.

---

I tried to get value from

```
alert($("selectedList option[value='" + value.value + "']"));
```

by using alert and the return value as **[object Object]**

---

while I tried to get value from

```
alert($("selectedList <option value='" + value.value + "'>"));
```

there is error message:

```
syntax error, unrecognized expression: selectedList <option value='42'>
```

---

I think, I have to check **selectList** syntax before I use it for *if* under **$.each** syntax.

Please, I need further advice for this JS/jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To find whether list is empty or not, is can be done using the following code after `$(selectedList).remove();`

```
$("#ID_Villages option").length;   //If 0 then no options in the select list
```

To check for duplicates, you can use something like:

```
$("selectedDesa option[value='42']").length;
```

If the value of above is `0` then no option found in the destination list. If the length is `1` then option already exists. You can replace the `value` attribute based on the selected option value from the source list.

**Update:**

There is no need to loop. You can use the logic as below:

```
var selectedList = $('#ID_Villages  option:selected').toArray();
var selectedVal = $('#ID_Villages  option:selected').val(); // New code
```

Then while checking for duplicates, use the below:

```
$("selectedDesa option[value='" + selectedVal + "']").length;
```

Comment: for $("#ID_Villages option").length; it works well but for detecting duplicate values I use $.each and I still struggle to write JS/jQuery.